# Is "let rise" grammatical in written English?

Tags: grammar

This video [teaches How to Make Homemade Bread Bowls](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=118)

> I've just kneaded the dough in my stand mixer you can also do it by
>   hand if you'd like until it's nice and
>   soft and smooth about five minutes
>   and then placing it in an oiled bowl
>   just give it a quick roll around in the
>   oil and covering with a damp cloth I'm
>   going to **let rise** until double in size
>   about 40 minutes

Is "let rise" grammatical in written english?

Comment: In this sentence, "let rise" is not correct.  As Lambie points out, it needs to be: "let **it** rise".  The "it" ponits to the thing - namely, the dough - which is rising.  Without the "it", the sentence does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**to let the dough or dough rise.**

Ergo, to **let it rise.**

Here, let takes a direct object.

[until it doubles in size]

Comment: what does "Ergo" mean here?

Comment: @zghqh It means therefore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I take this awswer to the question "Is 'let rise' grammatical in written english, following 'I'm going to'?" as a yes?

Comment: @zghqh going to is irrelevant to the let rise part of your question. I'm going to [whatever].

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of English expressions including the construction **going to let** followed by a verb, such as:

> A bird I'm going to let free
>   A string I'm going to let go
>   A greyhound I'm going to let run for the first time

Similarly, **I'm going to let rise** works but (as per Lambie's answer) it properly requires either **which I'm going to let rise** or **I'm going to let it rise**.

Given that the text comes from a video, it's likely that the speaker is more concerned with clear instructions than correct grammar. Few people use concise grammar in such circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for sure, the discussion is in terms of written english, right?

Comment: Answers on the site deal with both written (formal) and spoken (informal/idiomatic) English. But it often happens that transcribed audio does not follow grammatical rules.